Lifetime error on any declared closure in body of function with higher-order trait bound and associated type
I have this trait, which includes an associated type with a lifetime (Item<'a>). I call to that trait in a function which specifies the trait and the item in a generic clause (T<Item<'a> = &'a i32) that introduces the lifetime 'a with a higher-rank trait bound. However, when I added an unrelated closure to the function, it with the error message "[type] does not live long enough". Note that the variable of that type is not included in the closure. However, when the trait is refactored to specify Item in a trait generic, there is no error.
I am very reluctant to refactor the trait in that way for three reasons: it is less in keeping with standard practices; more importantly, because I don't want calls to the other members of that trait that aren't effected by the type Item or lifetime 'a to be colored with unnecessary attributes, and most importantly, it tends to give me a lot of "type is not constrained" errors. Like, code-breaking errors.
I'm going to provide first an example of the trait and function wherein Item is associated, wherein "Item" is overshadowed (associated and generic) and wherein Item is purely generic. Only the first example gave me the error.
trait T1 { //Ideal code that doesn't work
    type Item<'a> where Self: 'a;
}
trait T2<Item> { //Nonsense code that works
    type Item<'a> where Self: 'a;
}
trait T3<'a, Item: 'a> {} //Also works

fn f1<X: for<'a> T1<Item<'a> = &'a i32>>(x: X)->()
{
    let f = |a: i8|a; //`X` does not live long enough
}
fn f2<X: for<'a> T2<Item<'a> = &'a i32>>(x: X)->()
{
    let f = |a: i8|a;
}
fn f3<X: for<'a> T3<'a, &'a i32>>(x: X)->()
{
    let f = |a: i8|a;
}


T1::Item requires that Self: 'a, but f1 does not.  Since f1 is applicable for all 'a, including 'static, you are implying that X: 'static, however Rust requires that be stated explicitly: fn f1<X: 'static + for<'a> T1<Item<'a> = &'a i32>>(x: X) ....

Associated types are for types that need to be chosen by the implementor of the trait. Generic parameters are for types that need to be chosen by the user. You're not showing us the implementation, or anything that would require an associated type, so I'd say T3 is the idiomatic solution here.

f2 does not work, it does not compile!

@cafce25 "Internal compiler error" → you should report a bug to the Rust team. However it doesn't compile on older compilers either: https://godbolt.org/z/rTcKhYcWY

@Jmb thought about it but it is fixed in nightly already.

Sorry guys. Forgot I posted this for a week. Let me try and reply to these comments quickly.

@eggyal Wouldn't it be true that an HRTB lifetime would necessarily be outlived by the type which fulfils it? After all, this error isn't raised when no closure is specified. That's an thing I discovered later that I maybe should mention.

@cafce25 Oh, I'll test again, but f2 is really not that important to the problem.

@Jmb You're right, I didn't show the implementation, but I don't really get why you'd assume that T3 is idiomatic. The trait patterned like an iterator, so the type is chosen largely by the implementor. Like I said in the question, The actual trait contains other definitions which aren't affected by the lifetime 'a, so putting the lifetime in the type definition keeps my code free from unnecessary coloring.

@Jmb Found it https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/131677

@cafce25 It's fixed in nightly? Do you have any more information?

f2 is not an internal compiler error (a bug in the compiler) but just a regular compilation error with a nightly compiler.  The stable one ran into an ICE instead.
